# Ruby: Undefined local variable or method

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to store a hash within an array with the keys "name", "number", and "email". I want the email to be a user's last name + last 3 digits of the number + "@btvs.com". I keep getting the error "undefined local variable or method" for number. How can I get this to output correctly? It has no problem grabbing the value from "name", but won't from "number".

```
data = Array.new()

puts "Name?, eg. Willow Rosenberg"
name = gets.chomp

    data = [
        {
        name: name,
        number: rand(1000..9000) + 1,
        email: name.split(' ').last + number.to_s[1..3] + "@btvs.com"
        }
    ]

puts data
```

Comment: That's because `name` is set before you start initializing the array/hash. Why not do the same for `number`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly sorry I'm a bit new to this. What should I be setting number to?

Comment: `number = rand(1000..9000) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
puts "Name?, eg. Willow Rosenberg"
name = gets.chomp
number = rand(1000..9000) + 1
data = [
  {
    name: name,
    number: number,
    email: name.split(' ').last + number.to_s[-3, 3] + "@btvs.com"
  }
]
puts data
```

Comment: Why did you change `number.to_s[1..3]` to `number.to_s[-3, 3]`?

Comment: Because he said the last three digits of the number.

Comment: *Try [code dump]* with no explanation, leads to comments like my previous comment.

Comment: Sometimes people want explanation about one concept, other times they just want the code, see how they could solve their problem.

Comment: I didn't actually use number.to_s[-3, 3]. I kept my original formatting for that, but implemented the correct changes for setting "number" before the array.

Comment: @Ursus I need to loop this so the user is prompted with "Name?" 3 times, and each answer is stored as a new hash within the data array. Each answer should also have a new random number generated for it, and an email. Any ideas?

Comment: @morrime I think you should open another question. but before try on your own and tell us where you find difficulties.

Comment: @morrime I would add emphasis to Ursus point that you should **try on your own and tell us where you find difficulties**. You should also show that you have done a fair amount of research. Remember that asking a question on Stack Overflow should be your last option.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm a beginner and have been googling until my hands bleed for a day and a half. I have been researching and trying things on my own TO NO AVAIL. As a beginner, I cannot open another question for an hour and a half. So let's try not to be rude, shall we?

Comment: @morrime Sorry if I came off as sounding rude, that wasn't my intent. If you're having trouble learning Ruby, then you should check out [Codecademy's Ruby Course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/ruby), it's free, it's hands-on and does a pretty good job of conveying information.